# How can I access the user email associated to an object that implements the \Drupal\user\UserInterface interface?

Tags: 8, users

If a method of a class returns an object that implements the `\Drupal\user\UserInterface` interface, how can I access the user email associated to that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you have is a user entity object.

The user entity class has a `getEmail()` method, that you can use to get the user's email.

For more info look here, [User::getEmail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetEmail/8.2.x).

Answer (score 0):

Since the [`\Drupal\user\UserInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserInterface.php/interface/UserInterface/8.9.x) interface extends the [`\Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountInterface.php/interface/AccountInterface/8.9.x) interface, which makes available the [`getEmail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountInterface.php/function/AccountInterface%3A%3AgetEmail/8.9.x) method, you can use it to get the email associated with the returned object.
For example, if you stored the returned object in `$account`, you can access its email address with `$account->getEmail()`.

Do not confuse `\Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface::getEmail()` with [`\Drupal\user\UserInterface::getInitialEmail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserInterface.php/function/UserInterface%3A%3AgetInitialEmail/8.9.x). The latter returns the email address used when the account was registered, which can be later changed. To get the current email address, you need to call `\Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface::getEmail()`.